# I'm locked out of my MacBook pro because my password uses a russian keyboard but I can't change to it from the English keyboard

Tags: macos, mac, language, input-languages

Is there a way to change the language of the keyboard in Mac OS X 10.9.5, or even system language, while not logged into an account (as I restarted)?

This is my toolbar at the moment:

[image]

There is only the one account on the laptop. Are there no boot menus or anything like that? I’m accustomed to the Windows XP and that boot system, so I’d have a bit of an idea what I’m doing.

Also I have the password, in Russian characters, as the hint, but I can’t copy and paste.

**EDIT:** I Have solved it. For those with the same type of issue:

1. Restart, and press and hold <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> until and while the Apple symbol first shows up. This will open the utilities. Chose the language you speak.
2. Open the terminal (it's in one of the toolbar menus)
3. input: -bash-3.2# resetpassword
4. A window will pop up which will allow you to change the password for whatever the account is.
5. Follow the instructions, restart, go to the log-in page, enter your new password.
6. A window will pop up saying the following; I just pressed the “continue log in” button.:

   > The system was unable to unlock your login keychain.
7. I do believe a window should then pop up once you've logged in (which may take a little longer to load).
8. Create your new system password. Don't make the same mistake twice.

Disclaimer: This worked for me; I’m no expert. Be careful when changing system settings.

Comment: What operating system are you using.  Just because you have a MacBook does not mean we can assume your using OS X.  What you can do will entirely depend on what operating system your using so please update you question with that information it would a ton.

Comment: Do you have any other user accounts?  If you sudo password also contains Russian characters you might be out of luck without a Russian keyboard.

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @DavidPostill He doesn't have 15 reputation.

Comment: You should be able to move your solution into an answer now.